# Install Eclipse Photon over Oxygen Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-photon

If I install Photon over Oxygen on a Mac will my previous settings, plugins and preferences be preserved?

Comment: No, that will corrupt the existing installation. Preferences are stored in the workspace (in the `.metadata` subfolder) and plug-ins can be imported via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_.

Comment: Would I need to uninstall Oxygen to install Photon?

Comment: You do not need to uninstall Oxygen first. In your case, it would probably be easier to [upgrade your existing installation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Upgrading_existing_Eclipse_IDE_and_Installed_Features_to_newer_release).

Answer (score 0):

Installing it over will damage the existing installation.

**Upgrade your existing installation** instead: see Eclipse Wiki - [FAQ How do I upgrade Eclipse IDE? - Upgrading existing Eclipse IDE and Installed Features to newer release](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Upgrading_existing_Eclipse_IDE_and_Installed_Features_to_newer_release)